# Are the chart maps of a complex manifold necessarily biholomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

I know that the transition maps of a complex manifold are biholomorphic, but are the chart maps themselves also biholomorphic? I know that it is the case for real smooth manifolds (here the chart maps are diffeomorphisms). Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does it mean to say the chart map is a diffeomorphism if you have an abstract smooth manifold?

Answer (score -1):

By definition, if $g:U\subset\mathbb{C}\to g(U)\subset X$ is a chart, then the function $g^{-1}:g(U)\to U$ is holomorphic, because $g^{-1}\circ g:U\to U$ is holomorphic for being the identity function on $U$. Likewise, $g:U\to g(U)$ is holomorphic because $g^{-1}\circ g\circ i:U\to U$ is holomorphic, where $i$ is the identity function on $U$, which is also a chart of $\mathbb{C}$. It is a bit redundant because the definition of what functions are holomorphic on $X$ is made such that the charts are iso morphisms between their domain and their range in the corresponding category.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What about the case where the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ is the complex manifold we consider? I have constructed chart maps from $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$. Are they biholomorphic?

Comment: @mathismath The chars' domain and its range, not the whole manifold and the domain of the chart.